# Can't download software from external harddrive - software already exists

Tags: hacker-experience

So recently i started playing (the) hacker experience. Im really enjoying this game but for some reason somebody hacked me and deleted all my software. Now i've backed up some of my files but when i try to download them back to my 'software' folder it says the software already exists. Screenshots below to clarify.

[image]

*My software list*

---

[image]

*My external HD*

---

[image]

*The error message*

---

Is there something i can do to use my backed-up software again?

---

Unfortunatly after upgrading my seeker all the way from 1.0 till 3.0 i still wasn't able to see any software that might have been hidden. I decided to format my HDD and download everything then. This turned out to work. Thanks to gatherer818 and Schism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The software may have simply been hidden on your computer.  Your best bet to get your hands on a better Seeker, to locate things that are hidden on your own and other's servers.

In the short term, getting a more experienced player to unhide your software will help.

(Note, in the pictures you posted, that you *do* already have the Basic Cracker 1.1 on your server.  If that's what you're trying to download, then the error message is working normally.)

Important note:  Obviously some players that offer to help will be looking to take advantage of you instead.  You should make doubly sure to clear your logs before asking for their help and don't access your bitcoin wallet after they're done unless you've reset your IP address.  (Thank you to Schism for reminding me of this important point.)  There is a reputable unhide-my-stuff service on the Hacker Experience forums that I suggest you take advantage of.

Comment: This error is 100% caused by having a hidden copy. I would add that it's important to be careful; most people offering seek services are benevolent, but some are truly malicious. In particular, you should not donate bitcoins to them, lest they camp your logs and find your private key.

Comment: @Schism you are entirely correct, thank you.  Edited the answer.

Comment: A patch to change this is coming. Soon, if you download software that you already have but on a hidden state, it will simply overwrite it, instead of throwing an error.